Place double quotation marks around each string in array using VBA
I have an array that differs everytime in length that somewhat looks like the following when I print it:
PartList = Part1,Part2,Part4

and I want it to be
PartList = "Part1","Part2","Part4"

So I can use it further in my script after I split it.
It should be very simple but I want to know the easiest way. I cannot change the list by hand, because it is generated.

Just to check, is this to be used in a database query?

Assuming your array is really a string, the following code will break apart the string and rebuild it in the format you desire:
Private Function AddQuotes(ByVal PartList As String) As String
   Dim pl As Variant
   Dim p As Variant
   
   pl = Split(PartList, ",")
   
   For Each p In pl
      AddQuotes = AddQuotes & """" & p & ""","
   Next
   
   AddQuotes = Mid(AddQuotes, 1, Len(AddQuotes) - 1)
End Function


Another alternative using Regular Expressions and creating a new array with double quoted strings is;
Sub Test()
    Dim PartList(), strArray As String, regExp As Object
    Dim strList As String, newArray As Variant
    
    PartList = Array("Part1", "Part2", "Part4")
    
    strArray = Join(PartList, ",")
    
    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    regExp.IgnoreCase = True
    regExp.Global = True
    regExp.Pattern = "([A-Z0-9]+)"
    
    strList = regExp.Replace(strArray, """$1""")

    newArray = Split(strList, ",")
    
'    Show the first element of the new array
    MsgBox newArray(0)
    
    Set regExp = Nothing
End Sub


You can concatenate the quotation marks to each string in the array. For example, try this (open an immediate window to see the debug output):
Sub test()

Dim myStrings(1 To 3) As String
myStrings(1) = "Part1"
myStrings(2) = "Part2"
myStrings(3) = "Part3"

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(myStrings) To UBound(myStrings)
    Debug.Print "myStrings(" & i; ") = " & myStrings(i)
Next i

For i = LBound(myStrings) To UBound(myStrings)
    myStrings(i) = """" & myStrings(i) & """"
Next i

For i = LBound(myStrings) To UBound(myStrings)
    Debug.Print "myStrings(" & i; ") = " & myStrings(i)
Next i

End Sub

You should see this in the immediate window:

myStrings(1) = Part1
myStrings(2) = Part2
myStrings(3) = Part3
myStrings(1) = "Part1"
myStrings(2) = "Part2"
myStrings(3) = "Part3"

To put a quotation mark in a string literal you double it: "". You can also use chr(34). (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-data-type.)

To save myself counting quotation marks, I use chr(34), such that:
    Dim arr As Variant:  arr = Array("Cat", "House", "Goose")
    Dim i As Long:  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print Chr(34) & arr(i) & Chr(34)
    Next i



As one-liner:
PartList = """" & Replace(PartList, ",", """,""") & """"

or, to have it more readable:
Const Quote = """"
PartList = Quote & Replace(PartList, ",", Quote & "," & Quote) & Quote

